# Elasticsearch query innerobject

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to filter on an inner object but I'm not able to get my data. I have the following elasticsearch mapping:

```
{
  "settings" : {
    "number_of_shards" : 1,
    "analysis" : {
      "filter" : {
        "technologies_synonym" : {
          "type" : "synonym",
          "synonyms_path" : "elasticsearch/synonyms/technologies.txt"
        }
      },
      "analyzer" : {
        "technologies_synonyms" : {
          "tokenizer" : "whitespace",
          "filter" : ["standard", "lowercase", "stop", "technologies_synonym"],
          "type" : "custom"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "company" : {
      "properties" : {
        "name" : { "type" : "string", "store" : "yes" },
        "logo" : { "type" : "string", "store" : "yes" },
        "website" : { "type" : "string", "store" : "yes" },
        "employees" : { "type" : "string", "store" : "yes" },
        "technologies" : { "type" : "string", "store" : "yes", "analyzer" : "technologies_synonyms" },
        "locations" : {
          "properties": {
            "city" : { "type" : "string", "store" : "yes" },
            "country" : { "type" : "string", "store" : "yes" },
            "coordinates" : { "type" : "geo_point", "store" : "yes" },
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My mapping use an inner object for locations, because a company can be located in several places. I also tried to replace the inner object by a nested.

```
{
  "mapping" : {
    "properties" : {
      # ...
      "locations" : { "type" : "nested" }
    }
}
```

When I query my companies objects on the other fields, I'm able to get the expecting results, but when I filter on a country I have no results.

Tried queries:

```
curl 'http://localhost:9200/myapp/company/_search?pretty=true' -XPOST -d '{
   "query": {
     "filtered": {
       "query": { "match_all": {} },
       "filter": {
         "nested": {
           "path": "locations",
           "filter": {
             "bool": {
               "must": [
                 {
                   "term": { "locations.country": "France" }
                 }
               ]
             }
           }
         }
       }
     }
   }
 }

 curl 'http://localhost:9200/tekusage/company/_search?pretty=true' -XPOST -d '{
     "query": {
       "filtered": {
         "filter": {
           "bool": {
             "must": [
               {
                 "term": {
                   "technologies": "ruby"
                 }
               },
               {
                 "term": {
                   "company.locations.country": "France"
                 }
               },
               {
                 "term": {
                   "company.locations.city": "Lille"
                 }
               }
             ]
           }
         }
       }
     }
   }'
```

Do you have some idea to help me to get my data ?

Thanks,
Kevin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can tell, your problem is just that since you do not specify an analyzer for the `"locations.company"` field, it is analyzed with the [standard analyzer](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html), which means that `"France"` gets tokenized as `"france"` into the lookup table. Then you are trying a [term filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-filter.html) against that field, which means the filter text is not analyzed. The text `"France"` does not exist in the lookup table, so you get no results. But if you try querying `"france"` with what you have you should get a result.

Or if you change the `"locations.company"` to `""index": "not_analyzed""` in your mapping then you will get a hit on `"France"`.

By way of example in the first case (with `"nested"` type on `"locations"`, though it also works without that if you don't use a `"nested"` query), I built a simplified version of your index with a couple of docs:

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/test_index/" -d'
{
   "settings": {
      "number_of_shards": 1
   },
   "mappings": {
      "company": {
         "properties": {
            "name": {
               "type": "string"
            },
            "locations": {
               "type": "nested",
               "properties": {
                  "country": {
                     "type": "string"
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}'
```

then added a couple of docs:

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/test_index/company/1" -d'
{
    "name" : "company1",
    "locations" : [
        { "country" : "England" }
    ]
}'

curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/test_index/company/2" -d'
{
    "name" : "company2",
    "locations" : [
        { "country" : "France" }
    ]
}'
```

then query against it with `"france"`:

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/test_index/company/_search" -d'
{
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "query": {
            "match_all": {}
         },
         "filter": {
            "nested": {
               "path": "locations",
               "filter": {
                  "term": {
                     "locations.country": "france"
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}'
```

and I get the response:

```
{
   "took": 1,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "company",
            "_id": "2",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "name": "company2",
               "locations": [
                  {
                     "country": "France"
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

In the second case, I set up the same way but with `"index": "not_analyzed"` on the `"locations.country"` field:

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/test_index2/" -d'
{
   "settings": {
      "number_of_shards": 1
   },
   "mappings": {
      "company": {
         "properties": {
            "name": {
               "type": "string"
            },
            "locations": {
               "type": "nested",
               "properties": {
                  "country": {
                     "type": "string",
                     "index": "not_analyzed"
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}'

curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/test_index2/company/1" -d'
{
    "name" : "company1",
    "locations" : [
        { "country" : "England" }
    ]
}'

curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/test_index2/company/2" -d'
{
    "name" : "company2",
    "locations" : [
        { "country" : "France" }
    ]
}'
```

Then search with the filter text `"France"`

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/test_index2/company/_search" -d'
{
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "query": {
            "match_all": {}
         },
         "filter": {
            "nested": {
               "path": "locations",
               "filter": {
                  "term": {
                     "locations.country": "France"
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}'
```

and I get my result back this way too:

```
{
   "took": 1,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test_index2",
            "_type": "company",
            "_id": "2",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "name": "company2",
               "locations": [
                  {
                     "country": "France"
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

I used the `"nested"` type in these examples, but it works with an inner object as well (just use term filter in your query instead of nested filter).

Here is a runnable example you can play with:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/553e28fcf17d1ebd1d00bee38103d671d19ceb13

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your information. It works well. In my use case I have to filter on 2 nested fields and 2 "normal fields". Because I had been some troubles to write the request, I paste it as example :) : http://sense.qbox.io/gist/426f65bf1e51c574096b45210b6159788eb4f289